# MinTTY Unicode Support and Build Error

Tags: unicode, msys, build-error, mintty

I'm trying to use [MinTTY](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) with [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) (downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/mintty/)), and I've noticed that it doesn't seem to have Unicode support.

i.e.:

1. I can't paste Unicode text into it (it turns out garbage).
2. If I `cat` a Unicode file to the terminal (whether UTF-8 or UTF-16) I get back garbage.
3. If I use `ls` and a file *name* is Unicode, it prints out garbage. Piping the result to a file does **not** help -- it's *still* garbage even when viewed in a text editor with Unicode support.
4. I can't figure out how the `UTF-8` setting in the seettings works. It doesn't seem to change anything.
5. When I try to download the source and build it, I get build errors that I can't solve:

   ```
   Makefile:117: charset.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: child.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: config.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: ctrls.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: minibidi.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: std.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: term.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: termclip.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: termline.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: termmouse.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: termout.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: winclip.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: winctrls.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: windialog.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: wininput.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: winmain.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: winprint.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: wintext.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: wintip.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: xcwidth.d: No such file or directory
   Makefile:117: res.d: No such file or directory
   windres --preprocessor 'gcc -E -xc-header -DRC_INVOKED -MMD -MP 'res.rc res.o
   gcc xcwidth.c -c -MMD -MP  -include std.h -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror
       -Wundef -march=i586 -mtune=pentium-m -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -Os
   In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
   ./std.h:4:28: fatal error: cygwin/version.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   make: *** [xcwidth.d] Error 1
   ```

## Questions:

1. Is it possible to somehow get Unicode support in MSYS/MinTTY (it seems to be an issue with **both**)?
2. If *not*, then where do I get all those files like `charset.d`, and how do I build MinTTY for MSYS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mintty does support UTF-8. You can enable it on the Text page of its options.

MSYS does indeed not support it though. Instead, it uses the system's "ANSI" codepage, e.g. CP1252 on US and Western European systems. Therefore, that's what mintty for MSYS defaults too as well.

Furthermore, MSYS bash is set up such that it interprets the top bit of each character as the meta flag, so by default it can't handle anything beyond ASCII. To change that, put the following into `~/.inputrc`:

```
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
set convert-meta off
```

For full Unicode support (out-of-the-box), you need to use Cygwin 1.7 instead of the Cygwin 1.3 fork that is MSYS.

MSYS mintty needs to be built with the MSYS versions of gcc and make instead of the MinGW ones, because it requires POSIX functionality not provided by MinGW. Install them with `mingw-get install msys-gcc msys-make`, and stick the MSYS executables at the front of the path when running them: `PATH=/bin:$PATH make`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A few comments: (1) Changing the meta-bits still didn't print anything correctly -- even though I also changed the encoding to UTF-8. (2) I'm confused why you mention Cygwin; do I build it with MSYS or with Cygwin?

Comment: As I said, MSYS does not support UTF-8. Therefore's little point enabling it in the mintty options, unless you're using it primarily to ssh to systems that do support it. I mention Cygwin because MSYS is a modified Cygwin 1.3 (from ten years ago), which did not support UTF-8, whereas modern Cygwin (1.7) does. In other words: use Cygwin if you need a POSIX layer with UTF-8 support. MSYS mintty does needs to be built under MSYS.

Comment: Oh I see... it's a bummer MSYS doesn't support Unicode. Thanks for the info.